# Retrieving logged user group(s) with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to improve access on my web app.
All works fine but I need to retrieve the user group where my user is contained.
I've implemented the JdbcDaoImpl bean in my security xml and I've setting the properties groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery and allowing the query by usergroup. So, the app logins!
But I don't know how to get the group.
I need something like:
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getGroups()...
Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to do it with XML. Is necessary implements a security controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following which will return a list of `GrantedAuthority`

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                            .getAuthentication()
                                            .getAuthorities()
```

[GrantedAuthority.getAuthority()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html) will return your role.